# Get user input from optiongroup before proceeding

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database that generates test questions in a random order.  When I get the answer form (frmAnswers) to open, all I can do is have it scroll through all the questions using either the Enter or esc keys.  I have a MsgBox that pops up just to let me know some of the variables are set properly, but the code will not pause to accept input from the OptionGroup in the form.

Here is what I assume is the relevant code:

```
    Set rsCourse = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strCourse)

    DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmAnswers")

rcdCnt = 1

While Not rsCourse.EOF
    With rsCourse

        Screen.ActiveForm.ctlQ_No = rcdCnt
        Screen.ActiveForm.ctlQuestion = .Fields("Question")
        Screen.ActiveForm.ctlAns_A = .Fields("Ans A")
        Screen.ActiveForm.ctlAns_B = .Fields("Ans B")
        Screen.ActiveForm.ctlAns_C = .Fields("Ans C")
        Screen.ActiveForm.ctlAns_D = .Fields("Ans D")

        Forms!frmAnswers!optAnswer.SetFocus

        Select Case Forms.frmAnswers.optAnswer
            Case Is = 1:  strAns = "A"
            Case Is = 2:  strAns = "B"
            Case Is = 3:  strAns = "C"
            Case Is = 4:  strAns = "D"
            Case Is = Null:  srtAns = "Nothing"
        End Select

        If strAns = .Fields("Correct Answer") Then
        Exit Sub

        Else

        MsgBox "The correct answer is " & .Fields("Correct Answer") _
        & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "You answered " & strAns

        End If

    End With

    rcdCnt = rcdCnt + 1

    If rcdCnt > 100 Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    rsCourse.MoveNext

Wend
```

I have searched many sites, to include Microsoft, pcreview, accessmvp, etc., and have yet to find anything that helps.  I have tried;

```
    Select Case 
        Case 1
        Case 2
        Etc.
    End Select
```

as well as the code in my example.  Nothing seems to pause the code except the MsgBox.

I have also tried putting this code as a Function:

```
    Call TestClick(strCourse)
```

With the function:

```
    Function TestClick(strCourse)
```

with the above code in the function.  It returns a compile error: "Object required" at the Set rsCourse line.

I have also tried this as a subroutine with the same error.

For clairification, here is the code I have for the form that calls the frmAnswers Form:

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmIntroduction_VBA")

    If IsNull(Me.cboTrainee_Name) Then                                    ' No Name
        MsgBox "You must enter your name to continue!", vbOKOnly          ' Tell user
        Me.cboTrainee_Name.SetFocus                                       ' Focus the control
        Exit Sub                                                          ' Exit the method
    End If                                                                ' End the IsNull test

    Trainee_Name = Forms!frmIntroduction_VBA!cboTrainee_Name

    If IsNull(Me.cboCourse) Then                                          ' Check if a course is selected
        If IsNull(Me.cboVol) Then
            MsgBox "You must select either a Course or Volume Review to continue!"         ' Tell user
            Me.cboCourse.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.cboCourse) Then
        strCourse = Me.cboVol.Value
    Else
        strCourse = Me.cboCourse.Value
    End If
```

I would like this to actually call another Sub for the frmAnswers form, but do not know how to pass the rsCourse variable to the Sub.

I am sure this is a fairly easy issue to resolve, but I am no expert by any means.  Once I get this problem solved, I will continue on and try to have VBA create a recordset with test results to be appended to an existing table.

Thank you all for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: You should place your code in an optAnswer_AfterUpdate sub.  That way it will run after the user has made their selection from the option group.

Comment: I appreciate the input.  Can you provide an example.  I have edited my original question to show I have tried both sub routines and functions to no avail.

Comment: That won't solve the problem. AfterUpdate will properly trigger an event, but your given code will loop through every test question before the user can do anything. You need to get rid of the loop. Frankly, I'd get rid of the recordset altogether. Why not bind the form to the course table and apply filters to show each question, one at a time and use a submit button or AfterUpdate event to process the answer and move to the next question?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I have been having, the code keeps looping and will not wait for user input.  As far as the recordset, this identifies which test bank to open (it is a query).  I am not sure how I would bind the form to this variable otherwise.  If I do this, I assume a "Next Record" button would move to the next question in this query, am I correct?  Then I would need to somehow capture the response to the optiongroup.

Comment: Several ways to attack... Question: Do you want the person to select an answer and then click a 'Submit' button, or just select an answer and the rest happens automatically? (makes a difference where you put the code...)

Comment: @xpofer, I would prefer a 'Submit' button, although it would be interesting to see how many wrong answers they get if selecting the first answer they think is correct.  No, I'm not a sadist, so yes, a 'Submit' button would most likely be best.

Comment: @Wingrider, I'm going to start an answer, basically because it's easier to read.  I'll type up some code then you can leave comments on the answer and we'll keep refining the answer together until it's something useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just one of a million different ways of doing this.  My feelings aren't hurt if other people chime in with other ways.  But this solution may be most in-line with the road you're already headed down:

You need a way to pass your strCourse to the form.
-One way would be to declare a `String` variable `strCourse` in the frmAnswers class module and set it from the frmIntroduction_VBA after you open frmAnswers.
-Another way would be to create an invisible field on frmAsnwers called `strCourse` and set it after you open the form with `form!frmAnswers!strCourse=strCourse`.
-The easiest way I think for you would just be to refer to the frmIntroduction_VBA form *from* the frmAnswers form.  That's what we'll do here.

First things first:  Open frmAnswers.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm("frmAnswers")
```

Now let's move all the rest of your code into the frmAnswers form itself.  Here's the frmAnswers class module:

```
Option Explicit

'The following will be variables that will persist as long as the form is open

dim rsCourse as Recordset
dim strCourse as String
dim rcdCnt as Long
dim strCorrectAnswer as String

Private Sub Form_Load()    'This basically initializes the variables and loads the first question

    If IsNull(Forms!frmIntroduction_VBA!cboCourse) Then
        strCourse = Forms!frmIntroduction_VBA!cboVol
    Else
        strCourse = Forms!frmIntroduction_VBA!cboCourse
        End If

    Set rsCourse = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strCourse)

    rcdCnt = 0

    LoadNextQuestion

    End Sub



Private Sub LoadNextQuestion()   'reusable code to load questions

    rcdCnt=rcdCnt+1
    If (rcdCnt>100) OR rsCourse.EOF Then
        rs.Close
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmAnswers"
        Exit Sub
        End If

    With rsCourse
        ctlQ_No = rcdCnt
        ctlQuestion = !Question
        ctlAns_A = ![Ans A]
        ctlAns_B = ![Ans B]
        ctlAns_C = ![Ans C]
        ctlAns_D = ![Ans D]
        strCorrectAnswer = ![Correct Answer]
        optAnswer = Null   'clears previous answer
        optAnswer.SetFocus

        .MoveNext

        End With
    End Sub




Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    Dim strAnswer As String

    strAnswer = "Nothing"
    Select Case optAnswer
        Case 1:
            strAnswer = "A"
        Case 2:
            strAnswer = "B"
        Case 3:
            strAnswer = "C"
        Case 4:
            strAnswer = "D"
        End Select

    If strAns = strCorrectAnswer Then
        MsgBox "Correct!"
    Else
        MsgBox "The correct answer is " & strCorrectAnswer & "." _
            & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "You answered " & strAns &"."
        End If

    LoadNextQuestion

    End Sub
```

Start with that and play around with it.  If you're not sure why I did something a certain or if I missed some fundamental aspect of what you're doing, leave it in a comment and we'll keep refining it.

Comment: OMG, you're the man!  I had to tweak a couple of variables in the code but it works exactly as I need.  Now I just have to extract the number of questions answered incorrectly and the trainee's name, and append this to a table for future use.  I have been searching dozens of VBA sites looking for answers to my problems.  I figured the solution wouldn't be extremely difficult, but this appears to be a very simple process, if you know what you are doing.  Thank you very much, it is deeply appreciated.